# jquery plugin cannot get getJSON working

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
( function( $ ) {                

    function CleanQueryString( query )
    {
        return encodeURI( query ); 
    };

    function ConcatData( settings )
    {                               
        settings.concatUrl = settings.googleUrl;
        settings.concatUrl = settings.concatUrl.replace( "{key}", settings.googleApiKey );
        settings.concatUrl = settings.concatUrl.replace( "{country}", settings.country );     
        settings.concatUrl = settings.concatUrl.replace( "{query}", settings.cleanQuery );  
    };

    $.fn.GoogleSearchResult = function( options ) {  

        var settings = $.extend( {
            query: null,
            googleApiKey: "myapikey",
            googleUrl: "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key={key}&country={country}&q={query}&alt=json",
            concatUrl: "",
            country: "UK",
            cleanQuery: ""
        }, options);

        return this.each( function() {  
            if( settings.query )
            {   
                var $t = $(this);

                settings.cleanQuery = CleanQueryString( settings.query );
                ConcatData( settings );    
                alert( settings.concatUrl ); // This alerts the correct url and I've checked that it returns json

                $.getJSON( settings.concatUrl, function( data ) {  
                    alert("hi"); // This never alerts                    
                    $t.html( data );                
                });
            }

            return false;    
        } );     
    };  
} )( jQuery );
```

I can't get my $.getJSON to work.. any ideas why that might not be returning anything:

https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/getting_started

The url I send returns the correct data when I go straight to it.

Comment: Are you attempting to access JSON on a different server? If so, you need to load it on your own server using some kind of server-side script, and access *that* using `.getJSON`. [Google Shopping Search doesn't appear to offer JSON-P](https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/getting_started)

Comment: Chain `.error(function(xhr, status, error) { alert("error: " + status +" " + error); })` that on to it, and see what the error message is

Comment: yea, im using google search results api to get a result: https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/getting_started

Comment: @JamesT Well, [that answers that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5241088/901048).

Comment: That means that the error is because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) so you need to wrap your data as jsonp, as someone said

Comment: Ahh it's coz im running it from my localhost.. I'll check that jsonp out.

Comment: jQuery.support.cors = true; Seemed to answer the question. Thanks buddy

Comment: This won't fix your problem of cross-domain but FWIW, here is a version I've come up with to simplify your code and gain a little performance. It also provides a debug option, and uses `$.ajax` instead of the shortcut `$.getJSON` so that an error method can be used (lack of error method is part of what took you so long to discover the issue). http://pastie.org/private/c0l8fyf0aqn4o4pvrjjwsg

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to access JSON on a different server? If so, you need to load it on your own server using some kind of server-side script, and access that using `.getJSON`. [Google Shopping Search doesn't appear to offer JSON-P](https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/getting_started).

If you can write a PHP page or some other server-side language, [it's trivial to get and return the external JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13709674/901048), which will now be on your *own* server and can be easily loaded using `.getJSON`.

Comment: It does support JSONP, though it doesn't say on that page.

Comment: jQuery.support.cors = true; This was the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.getJSON( settings.concatUrl, function( data ) {  
    alert(data);                    
    $t.html( data );                
}).error(function(xhr, status, error) { alert("error" + status +" " + error); }) ;
```

Jquery cross domain support can be enabled with this setting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSONP to transfer data from an external source. The Google API supports this, so in terms of your code, this is as simple as appending `&callback=xyz` to your url, where `xyz` is some function that the external server will wrap your code in.

> `https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key={key}&country={country}&q={query}&alt=json&callback=xyz`

jQuery automatically looks for a callback named `?`, so you can either use `callback=?` or specify a custom name by adding `jsonp: xyz` to your AJAX request params.